# How to create an archive with Zippy on Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I use Laravel 4 framework for PHP and have successfully added this module called Zippy for creating archive files but it seems to be bouncing back an error saying

> Unable to create archive

Please can you suggest a solution for a different package or how to get around with this error?

PHP Code:

```
use Alchemy\Zippy\Zippy;

$zip = Zippy::load();
$zip->create('testingit.zip', array(
        "assets/img/logo.png"
        ),$recursive = true);
```

Comment: can you show us some code please?

Comment: I've added the code into the question

Comment: Where is `assets/img/logo.png` located? Use `public_path()` to get the absolute path to the public directory

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem in one server and the solution was these two things:

1. Make sure **zip** is installed
   **sudo apt-get install zip** or **yum install zip unzip**
2. Make sure your enviroment variable PATH is set using phpinfo() or getenv('PATH')

In my case I' using php-fpm, I just had to add this line in ***/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf***

```
env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

Comment: Am on shared hosting.